# Ionic 3, firebase save values in two databases under same key

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ionic3

I'm working with ionic project and I'm using databases in firebase to store data.
Here I want to create values in two databases with the same key when a new value is entered.

First I tried to get the key of one database and use that key to store value in other databases.

```
this.database.list("/User/").push({
       Username: this.username.value,
       Email: this.email.value,
       Shop: this.shopname.value,
       Contact: this.contact.value
       }).then((data)=>
       console.log(data.key));

this.database.list("/Shops/").push(data.key).set(
         this.shopname.value
      );
```

Then I tried to get a key and set it to both of the databases.

```
let key = this.database.createPushId();

this.database.list("/Shops/").push(key).set(
         this.shopname.value
      );
```

nothing worked for me.
I'm a beginner to ionic and the similar question that are already asked did not give me any solution
If any need I'm using

```
angularfire2: "^5.0.0-rc.11",
firebase : "^4.13.1",
ionic 3
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time your call `push()` you get a reference to a **new child with a unique ID**. Since you want to create two new child nodes with the same ID, you should only call `push()` once. It's easiest to separate the call to `push()` from the code that writes:

```
var key = firebase.database().ref("/User/").push().key;
```

This call doesn't actually do anything in the database; it doesn't even call to the server. It merely generates a key that is statistically guaranteed to be unique. You can then use this key in both write operations:

```
firebase.database().ref("/User").child(key).set({
    Username: this.username.value,
    Email: this.email.value,
    Shop: this.shopname.value,
    Contact: this.contact.value
})
firebase.database().ref("/Shops").child(key).set(
    this.shopname.value
);
```

The above uses the JavaScript SDK directly, instead of AngularFire2. Since AngularFire2 is built on top of the JavaScript SDK, they work together perfectly, so the above writes will be picked up by any observers you may have on the lists.